# Maintaining user session without having user saved in django authentication system

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am having a small Django app in which users need to be authenticated externally via Webgate plugin installed on Apache. Webgate will use other enterprise authentication system hosted on the intranet to authenticate the users coming into my django site. Once the enterprise authentication system authenticates the user, it will redirect them to our site with a header REMOTE-USER. This header will contain the username. I need to just make sure that user mentioned in that header is able to access to the site even though it does not exist on my site, trusting that he is already authenticated.
For this I am using

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
]
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
)
```

**This works. But it creates users in the site. Requirement is that users must not exist in our database. They can exist in memory. They need to have a session**
Is this even possible in Django? If yes, how I could achieve this?
I tried subclassing AllowAllUsersRemoteUserBackend as below and overriding authenticate method to return a user which is just in memory, not in DB.

```
class AllowAllUsersRemoteUserBackendWithoutCreatingUnknownUsers(AllowAllUsersRemoteUserBackend):

    create_unknown_user = False

    def authenticate(self, request, remote_user):
        return User(username = remote_user)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'polls.middleware.authentication.AllowAllUsersRemoteUserBackendWithoutCreatingUnknownUsers',
)
```

But with this I get an exception

```
ValueError at /polls/
Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8001/polls/
Django Version: 2.1.7
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key.
Exception Location: C:\Users\rizwan_shaikh\Envs\sessiontest\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py in _save_table, line 803
Python Executable:  C:\Users\rizwan_shaikh\Envs\sessiontest\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\ApplicationCode\\Kenstar\\sessiontest\\djangosessiontestwithwsgi',
 'C:\\Users\\rizwan_shaikh\\Envs\\sessiontest\\Scripts\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\rizwan_shaikh\\Envs\\sessiontest\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\rizwan_shaikh\\Envs\\sessiontest\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\rizwan_shaikh\\Envs\\sessiontest\\Scripts',
 'c:\\softwares\\pythoninstallation\\Lib',
 'c:\\softwares\\pythoninstallation\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\rizwan_shaikh\\Envs\\sessiontest',
 'C:\\Users\\rizwan_shaikh\\Envs\\sessiontest\\lib\\site-packages',
 '/app',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 30 Jan 2020 08:37:34 +0000
```

Right now I am not running my code on apache, rather I am running on django development server. I am manually adding the header containing username via another middleware. Aim is to get the basic stuff working, then will deploy code to apache.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by using below settings.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',  
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'module.CheckIDMHeaderMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [],
    'UNAUTHENTICATED_USER': None,
}
```

Had to create my own User class.

```
class User:
username = ''
user_permissions = []
is_active = True

def get_user_permissions(self):
    return self.user_permissions

def __init__(self, username):
    self.username = username
    self.is_active = True
```

In CheckIDMHeaderMiddleware's **call** method I am reading the header containing username obtained from webgate plugin. Using that username I am created a User object and setting in it session.

```
def __call__(self, request):
    # some code skipped to keep the answer simple.
    ....
    username = request.META[header_name]
    user = User(username = username)
    request.user = user
    response = self.get_response(request)
    return response
    ....
    # some code skipped to keep the answer simple.
```

....